# Append canvas elements to a group

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas, grouping, diagram

I want to group elements and when these elements are dragged over the rectangle(group) element, they move with each other
How to implement such a feature? Is there a way to know whether an element is on top of that element and append it to it as a child or any other solution

```js
const elements = [
  { // this is the rectangle which I want to append elements to it
    id: '1',
    type: 'group',
    data: {
      label: 'node 1',
    },
    position: { x: 250, y: 0 },
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    type: 'ec2',
    data: {
      label: 'node 2',
    },
    position: { x: 100, y: 100 },
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    type: 's3',
    data: {
      label: 'node 3',
    },
    position: { x: 80, y: 120 },
  }
];
```

[image]

Getting positions of elements
[image]

> P.S: I am using **React.js** & [react-flow-library](https://reactflow.dev/examples/) (If that could help)

Comment: Sure, but it depends entirely on the code you've already written. Conceptually you just need to make sure to actually work with objects that have positional information (like x/y/w/h value) and then it's a simple matter of checking bounding box overlap.

Comment: getting the position is easy, but how to drag & drop them together is the real challenge

Comment: Nowhere near as much as you're thinking: track your click-drag delta (not the "current mouse position" but "the delta wrt the coordinate the initial mousedown happened"), and then apply it to an array of items as "temporary offset" that gets taken into account when drawing your objects. Then when you let go of the mouse, you commit the change to the real x/y and set the offsets to 0/0.